# Issue assigning environments to list in R

Tags: r

I'm having a weird issue inserting an environment into a list.  If there are already items in the list, I get an error adding the environment using brackets, but not if I use dollar sign notation. If the list is empty, I don't get an error when assigning using brackets but it results in a list that is still empty.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
> x <- list()
> x['a'] <- 3    
> x['b'] <- baseenv()
Error in x["b"] <- baseenv() :
  environments cannot be coerced to other types
> x$b <- baseenv()
> x
$a
[1] 3

$b
<environment: base>
> y <- list()
> y['env'] <- baseenv()
> y
list()
```

R and Platform info:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: `x$b` is equivalent to `x[['b']]` rather then `x['b']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of the single square brackets:

```
x['b'] <- baseenv()
```

is actually a list replacement. You select a list of elements (in this case, a list containing only an element b) and you should replace that with another list. However, you give an environment there. In the replacement you use, you need to provide a list on the right hand side as well. If not, R will try to convert the object on the right to a list. This generates the error you see.

Take a look at the following example:

```
> x <- list(
+   a= 1:10,
+   b= "hello"
+ )

> x['b']
$b
[1] "hello"


> x[['b']]
[1] "hello"
```

Notice that the selection `x['b']` returns a **list**, whereas `x[['b']]` returns the element itself. The same goes for `x$b`, which is equivalent to using the double brackets.

So you have three options here to include an environment in that list:

```
x['b'] <- list(baseenv())
x[['b']] <- baseenv()
x$b <- baseenv()
```

If you use single square brackets, you shouldn't forget to have that list on the right hand side.

Comment: Gaaahhhhh, I need more coffee. Thanks for catching that.